# How to set HTML lang attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

We have a project contains a lot of HTML files. Unfortunately, we have recognized we should have used lang tag for our HTML files. We use AngularJS and Java.

Is there any way to set all pages HTML lang?

Comment: What platform do you use?

Comment: In java, what framework do you use?

Comment: we use our own framework

Comment: any client side or server side solution fine for us

Comment: It can be helped you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461711/angularjs-dynamic-lang-attribute-of-html

Comment: I have seen this link but we have to add this to every page which is what we don't want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple directive:

```
myApp.directive('html', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set("lang", "en");    // Set the "lang" value dynamically here
        }
    };
}]);
```

Just make sure the app is initialized at `html` tag i.e. `<html ng-app>` and you don't have to do this in your every page.

Comment: yeah, this is absolutely what I am looking for. Very smart :). Thanks a lot