# The <html> tag is automatically generated and I want <html lang="en">

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to use any javascript or jquery which on page load will add attribute LANG=EN to the web page. I tried using $('html').attr('name', 'value'); so still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461711/angularjs-dynamic-lang-attribute-of-html

Comment: @GANI, the question you linked has to do with AngularJS, not JS in general, as the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery to change the doc type and `<html>` tag is the absolutely the worst way to do what you need. jQuery rewrites the DOM, not real page source. jQuery is not intended to change such things as `<html>` tags.

You need to edit the theme you are using. The `<html>` is being output by your `header.php` file of the theme. If you really want `<html lang="en">`, edit `header.php`.

And read [What is lang attribute of the <html> tag used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649798/what-is-lang-attribute-of-the-html-tag-used-for)